# ImportError: No module named request Twitter API

Tags: python, request

I keep getting this error when trying to access the Twitter API. I'm running python 2.7 and I've installed `requests` and `requests-oauthlib` already.

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    import urllib.request as urllib2
ImportError: No module named request
```

Do I need to install another module for this to work? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try replacing import statement `import urllib.request as urllib2` with `import requests as urllib2` for Python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

You want to use python 3 not 2. Under python 2, it's just called `requests`

Comment: I have to use python 2.7 for my class but at the top of my program I already have `import requests_oauthlib`, so I think the problem is somewhere in the `requests_oauthlib` module?